# Can't select text in HTA modeless dialog

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, hta, modeless

Normally in an HTML file you can use the mouse to select and copy text or by pressing CTRL+A and CTRL+C. This even works in HTA programs on Windows systems.

However, I am unable to do this when I create a modeless dialog window using `window.showModelessDialog()` in the HTA file. The HTML document is loaded and displayed properly, but I am unable to select/highlight any text in the child window using the mouse or CTRL+A and CTRL+C.

Is there a workaround? If I try to use `window.open()` instead, then it opens a full-blown browser window including address bar, tabs, menu bar, etc. Also, the child window uses IE version 11 instead of version 7 used for the HTA program. I want to avoid doing this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[edit]

Here are the top few lines of the child HTA file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="Yes" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="../toee_raw_checker.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <TITLE>Calculations</TITLE>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
            ID = "oApp"
            APPLICATIONNAME = "ToEE RAW Checker Calculations"
            BORDER = "thick"
            CAPTION = "yes"
            ICON = "toee_raw_checker.ico"
            SHOWINTASKBAR = "yes"
            SINGLEINSTANCE = "no"
            WINDOWSTATE = "normal"
            SCROLL = "no"
            SCROLLFLAT = "yes"
            VERSION = "0.6.1"
            INNERBORDER = "no"
            SELECTION = "yes"
            SYSMENU = "yes"
            MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "yes"
            MINIMIZEBUTTON = "yes"
            NAVIGABLE = "yes"
            CONTEXTMENU = "yes"
            BORDERSTYLE = "thin"
        />
```

Comment: Set `selection="yes"` attribute within `<HTA:application>` tag.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you loading a HTA or a HTML file to the dialog? `HTA:application` doesn't have any effect in HTML document.

Comment: I've tried both HTA and HTML. It makes no difference. I updated my initial post with the relevant code.